# HTML dropdown functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML dropdown list:

```
<select>
 <option value="PK" style=""><span>Pakistan</span></option>
 <option value="UAE">United Arab Emirates</option>
 <option value="CA">Canada</option>
 <option value="GR">Germany</option>
</select>
```

I design it like it :

```
select option {
    padding-left:30px;

}
select option[value="PK"] {
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(https://d2ijupb52dd0cs.cloudfront.net/assets/flags/pk-43250eed6afece188d65e2d313b825a6.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 2px;
}
select option[value="UAE"] {
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(http://pcache.alexa.com/images/flags/ae.7391e6b6df7b181d51ffeb2a5a6d7bd4.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 2px;
}
select option[value="CA"] {
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(http://usefulshortcuts.com/imgs/flags/ca.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 2px;
}
select option[value="GR"] {
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(http://www.ardentvigor.com/skin/frontend/default/sm_nik/images/flags/flag-german.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 2px;
}
```

Check it out on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6k68s3cf/7/), now I want that when I click on any dropdown, some like I click on `Canada` instead of showing name in `select`, menu show me the flag of that country which I selected.

Comment: you can use jquery for this.  Onchange event will help you.

Comment: Can you help me for that cause I tried that but its not work for me. May be I used it on wrong way.

Comment: please check my answer. ty

Comment: please check my final demo. Hope it will work for you. M done with html css part now working functionality is upto you. If you are ok with my solution then please accept as answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easy and learnable code then go with this fiddle. Easy to understand.

First use jquery onchange event to get the option movement and then add css with `.css` properties in empty div to show the flag. Sorry for not putting flag inside option box as it will be little bit tough and need more customized code but i made it simple so you can also understand.

Hope you will get my point and made by your own. Let me know if you have any question. Thanx

[Final Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6k68s3cf/19/)

Comment: Great work! Thanks alot, you did great. but I don't need this as you see in select field, after selecting Pakistan it show Pakistan I want that instead of showing Pakistan select field show me the flag of Pakistan nor name.

Comment: ohh so you dont need name? wait i have updated fiddle..give me 2 min plz.

Comment: Yeah sure I am checking continuously, your work is great.

Comment: IF you don't mind please check [Gmail](http://mail.google.com) signup form. In that form they want our number. I want exactly that type of functionality.

Comment: aaah sorry mate as in office and cant do that much work..but will try..sorry for late

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below link. Did you mean the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/TxAhb/

```
    (function ($) {
    // size = flag size + spacing
    var default_size = {
        w: 20,
        h: 15
    };

    function calcPos(letter, size) {
        return -(letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97) * size;
    }

    $.fn.setFlagPosition = function (iso, size) {
        size || (size = default_size);

        var x = calcPos(iso[1], size.w),
            y = calcPos(iso[0], size.h);

        return $(this).css('background-position', [x, 'px ', y, 'px'].join(''));
    };
})(jQuery);

// USAGE:

(function ($) {

    $(function () {
        var $target = $('.country');

        // on load:
        $target.find('i').setFlagPosition('es');

        $('select').change(function () {
            $target.find('i').setFlagPosition(this.value);
            $target.find('b').text($(this).find(':selected').text());
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great! but actually I don't need this I want that when I select any country Instead of showing Country name it show me the flag. Check mobile number in [gmail](http://www.gmail.com) exactly I want this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use simple Way --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#country').change(function(){
            var country = $('#country').val(); //get  country val
            var flag = $('option[value=' + country + ']').css('background-image'); // get url('link')
            var url = flag.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, ''); // it replace url , ( and get only img link
            $('div.flat-img').html('<img src="' + url + '">'); // it will add html with flag
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hey MHK, i have uploaded my code on codepen and codepen link is -http://codepen.io/soravgarg/pen/oXJZLB  and code of Leo the lion will work only current countries  not worked for another countries but my code will work for all countries..

Comment: MHK have u checked it ??

Comment: Yes I checked it but I don't need this dude. I want this flag in place of name after selection. Check it on gmail sign up form, Mobile Number.

Comment: @sauravgarg, can you please tell me why my code won't work for other countries? and fyki i have used only 4 country as he mentioned or else i can show all countries with flag but it was not necessary so please use your words in better way.

Comment: now u have changed your code ..it was different before some hours ago...but your current code will worked for all countries..